# How do filesystem commit interval options interact with vm.dirty_expire_centisecs?

Tags: linux, filesystems

## Question

How do filesystem "commit interval" options interact with `vm.dirty_expire_centisecs`?  What happens when one is shorter than the other?  Does it ever make sense to set these differently?

My understanding is that filesystem commit interval settings control how often the filesystem will proactively write dirty data and metadata to disk, even when `fsync` hasn't been called by the application.

Separately, `vm.dirty_expire_centisecs` seems to have a similar role, but at the VM layer rather than the filesystem layer.

---

## References

[ext4 `commit` mount option](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt):

> Ext4 can be told to sync all its data and metadata every 'nrsec' seconds. The default value is 5 seconds. This means that if you lose your power, you will lose as much as the latest 5 seconds of work (your filesystem will not be damaged though, thanks to the journaling).

[btrfs `commit` mount option](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs(5)#MOUNT_OPTIONS):

> Set the interval of periodic commit. Higher values defer data being synced to permanent storage with obvious consequences when the system crashes.

Note, I'm leaving out XFS for now, as its [`fs.xfs.xfssyncd_centisecs`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/xfs.txt) option appears to apply to metadata only.

[`vm.dirty_expire_centisecs`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt):

> This tunable is used to define when dirty data is old enough to be eligible
>   for writeout by the kernel flusher threads.  It is expressed in 100'ths
>   of a second.  Data which has been dirty in-memory for longer than this
>   interval will be written out next time a flusher thread wakes up.

Comment: See also a copy of this question posted to the linux-ext4@ mailing list: https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-ext4/msg68621.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I [posted this question](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-ext4/msg68621.html) to the [linux-ext4@ mailing list](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#linux-ext4), and the answer from Jan Kara was:

> Yes, the effect is rather similar but not quite the same. The first thing to observe is kind of obvious fact that ext4 commit interval influences just the particular filesystem while dirty_expire_centisecs influences behavior of global writeback over all filesystems.
>
> Secondly, commit interval is really the maximum age of ext4 transation.  So if there is metadata change pending in the journal, it will become persistent at latest after this time. So for say 'mkdir' that will be persistent at latest after this time. For data operations things are more complex. E.g. when delayed allocation is used (which is the default), the change gets logged in the journal only during writeback. So it can take up to dirty_expire_centisecs for data to be written back from page cache, that results in filesystem journalling block allocations etc. and then it can
>   take upto commit interval for these changes to become persistent. So in this case the intervals add up. There are also other special cases somewhere in between but generally it is reasonable to assume that data gets automatically persistent in dirty_expire_centisecs + commit_interval time. Note both these times are actually times when writeback is triggered so if the disk gets too busy, the actual time when data is completely on disk may be much higher.

Answer (score 1):

It just influence the frequency actual logic is with kernel. I don't think if you give less value it will be effective, it take kernel defaults.

```
{
    .procname   = "dirty_expire_centisecs",
    .data       = &dirty_expire_interval,
    .maxlen     = sizeof(dirty_expire_interval),
    .mode       = 0644,
    .proc_handler   = proc_dointvec_minmax,
    .extra1     = &zero,
}
```

When the first page is dirtied in an inode, the current time is recorded in the inode. When this time gets older than dirty_expire_centisecs, all dirty pages in the inode are written. So with this mechanism in mind the behavior you describe looksexpected to me.

```
unsigned int dirty_expire_interval = 30 * 100; /* centiseconds */
```